# Writing a hybrid method using pathlib (accessing properties)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do some path-checking logic on some values in a database. I'm having trouble implementing the class level expression for the hybrid method.

Here is some stripped down code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, func, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, aliased, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property, hybrid_method
from pathlib import Path
import sqlalchemy as sa


dbEngine = create_engine(
    "sqlite:///.sql_app.db", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=dbEngine)
Base = declarative_base()


class Folder(Base):
    __tablename__ = "folder"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    fpath = Column(String, index=True)

    @hybrid_method
    def test_path(self, fpath):
        a = Path(fpath)
        b = Path(self.fpath)
        return a in [b] + [p for p in b.parents]

    @test_path.expression
    def test_path(cls, fpath):
        a = func.Path(fpath)
        b = func.Path(cls.fpath)
        
        # return a in [b] + [p for p in b.parents]
        # What to do here
        return (
            select([func.Path(Folder.fpath)]).
            label("fpath_in_folder")
        )


@sa.event.listens_for(sa.engine.Engine, "connect")
def sqlite_engine_connect(dbapi_conn, connection_record) -> None:
    dbapi_conn.create_function("Path", 1, Path)


def db_create_row(db: Session, value: int, fpath: str):
    folder = Folder(value=value, fpath=fpath)
    db.add(folder)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(folder)


# Determine if the supplied path is a sub path of any records in the table
def db_query_row(db: Session, fpath: str):
    records = db.query(Folder).filter(Folder.test_path(fpath) == True)
    return records


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=dbEngine)
    db = SessionLocal()

    db_create_row(db, 5, "/folder 1/folder 2/file.ext")
    records = db_query_row(db, "/folder 1")
    print(records.count())
    db.close()
```

I'm getting the error: `Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'parents'`
So I have to create a SQL expression for this function, but I'm not sure how, or if it's even possible with accessing the `parents` property on the Path object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite can't handle *Python instances*, and SQLAlchemy `Function` support doesn't cover instance methods either.

First of all, you can't use `Path()` objects as a SQLite function, as explained in the [`sqlite3.Connection.create_function` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function):

> The callable must return [a type natively supported by SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-types).

The natively supported types are `None`, `float`, `int`, `str` or `bytes` values.

The error you see comes from your attempt to use `b.parents` in your expression; `b` is the `Function` object, the `func.Path(...)` call, and SQLAlchemy expects a function to return a SQL type, not a `Path()` object.

Instead of trying to shoehorn `Path()` objects into SQLite, you'll need to find another way to test if a path is a parent folder. You could use [`Column.startswith()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/core/metadata.html?highlight=startswith#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.startswith) here, provided you first ensure the paths don't end with `/`, by using [the standard `RTRIM()` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#rtrim):

```
@test_path.expression
def test_path(cls, fpath):
    a = func.rtrim(fpath, "/")
    b = func.rtrim(cls.fpath, "/")

    return a == b or b.startswith(a + "/")
```

This will produce a SQL expression like this:

```
(
    rtrim(?, '/') == rtrim(folder.fpath, '/')
 OR rtrim(folder.fpath, '/') LIKE rtrim(?, '/') || '/' || '%'
)
```